# group zip codes by zones (North, east, west, South) sql

Tags: sql

I have this type of data for France and I want to group those zipcodes into 4 categories south/north/east/West using SQL. Is this possible? 
I can say that if latitude > 48 and longitude > 2.5, the region is called North-East. If latitude >48 and longitude<2.5 the region is called North-Ouest. If latitude<48 and longitude>2.5 the region is called South East and of latitude <48 and longitude <2.5 then region is called South Oues
Thanks

```
+---------+------------------------+------------+-------------------+
| zipcode |          city          |  latitude  |     longitude     |
+---------+------------------------+------------+-------------------+
|   13210 | Saint-Rémy-de-Provence | 43.788652  | 4.831343          |
|   13800 | Istres                 | 43.506196  | 4.99036599999999  |
|   37000 | Tours                  | 47.3951208 | 0.693232599999988 |
|   78480 | Verneuil-sur-Seine     | 48.9796889 | 1.97723380000002  |
|   95150 | Taverny                | 49.0243127 | 2.22085059999995  |
|   91300 | Massy                  | 48.73027   | 2.28712500000006  |
|   69800 | Saint-Priest           | 45.7168398 | 4.92662189999999  |
|   17870 | breuil magne           | 45.9840161 | -0.9589952        |
|   76100 | Rouen                  | 49.4341826 | 1.08828110000002  |
|   38500 | Voiron                 | 45.3520189 | 5.57151959999999  |
|   31500 | Toulouse               | 43.6010501 | 1.46503830000006  |
|   78400 | Chatou                 | 48.9027528 | 2.15630869999995  |
|   94000 | Créteil                | 48.7968017 | 2.44876620000002  |
|   69700 | Loire-sur-Rhône        | 45.5604967 | 4.80611650000003  |
+---------+------------------------+------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: what is your criteria for establishing North, East, South, and West? Is it a specific latitude and longitude that dictates that? How do you determine to label it as North/South vs East/West? This IS possible, but you need to decide on how it should be determined...

Comment: I have no idea of the criteria that can be used. I need guidance for that too

Comment: I know that the city in the extreme north of France is Bray-Dunes with a latitude of 51.0833 and a longitude of 2.5167. The city is the extreme east has a latitude of 48.9833 and longitude of 8.1833. The city in the extreme south has a latitude of 42.3603 and a longitude of 2.52028. The city in the extreme west has a latitude of 48.391541 and a longitude of -4.788666. I have no idea how to work with this

Comment: It's strange because you're trying to determine N/S based on latitude and E/W on longitude... You need to answer "N/E/S/W of what point (lat and long)?" Also, What about NorthEast, NorthWest, SouthEast, and SouthWest which evaluates both? How does one outweigh the other?

Comment: If you don't exactly know which zip-codes belong to which regions, there is not much hope with SQL. Tableau comes to mind though. See if this helps https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/maps_custom_territories.htm

Comment: If I had this task, I'd go back and ask the Business Owner or Stakeholder to give me a clarifications on what is considered N/S/E or W. Until then, I wouldn't be able to classify them correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I get to decide what is considered as North/East/West/South. If I take latitude equal to 48 and Longitude equal to 2.5 being the coordinates of the center of France. I can say that if latitude > 48 and longitude > 2.5, the region is called North-East. If latitude >48 and longitude<2.5 the region is called North-Ouest. If latitude<48 and longitude>2.5 the region is called South East and of latitude <48 and longitude <2.5 then region is called South Ouest

Comment: @poofidoudou what sql database are you using? ie: sql server, mysql, oracle, etc.

Comment: I am using SQL on Mode Analytics https://mode.com/

Answer (score 0):

> I can say that if latitude > 48 and longitude > 2.5, the region is called North-East. If latitude >48 and longitude<2.5 the region is called North-Ouest. If latitude<48 and longitude>2.5 the region is called South East and of latitude <48 and longitude <2.5 then region is called South Ouest.

It sounds like a `case` expression:

```
select . . . ,
       (case when latitude >= 48 and longitude > 2.5
             then 'Northeast'
             when latitude <= 48 and longitude > 2.5
             then 'Southeast'
             when latitude > 48 and longitude <= 2.5
             then 'Northwest'
             when latitude < 48 and longitude <= 2.5
             then 'Southwest'
        end)
```